# Error get data by retrofit2

Tags: java, android, json, http, retrofit2

I want to get data from URL

`http://cloud.traffy.in.th/apis/apitraffy.php?api=get_bus_line_info&appid=51248f9a&bus_line={bus_line}`

and `{bus_line}`from edittext

example

`http://cloud.traffy.in.th/apis/apitraffy.php?api=get_bus_line_info&appid=51248f9a&bus_line=17`

but I try get data by retrofit2 and now I get error

> D/Resultttt: Not Found

Bus.java

public class Bus {

```
  @SerializedName("bus_line")
  @Expose
  private String busLine;
  @SerializedName("start")
  @Expose
  private String start;
  @SerializedName("end")
  @Expose
  private String end;
  @SerializedName("vehicle_type")
  @Expose
  private String vehicleType;
  @SerializedName("owner")
  @Expose
  private String owner;
  @SerializedName("route_type")
  @Expose
  private String routeType;
  @SerializedName("bus_line_id")
  @Expose
  private String busLineId;

  public String getBusLine() {
    return busLine;
  }

  public void setBusLine(String busLine) {
    this.busLine = busLine;
  }


  ....

}
```

Getbus.java

```
      public interface Getbus {
  @GET("apis/apitraffy.php")
  Call<Bus> select(@Query("api") String api, @Query("appid") String appId, @Query("bus_line") String bus_line);
}
```

and MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      Button button;
      EditText editText;
      TextView textView;
      private Getbus getbus;
      private String BASE_URL = "http://cloud.traffy.in.th/";
      private String TAG = "fong";

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build();

        getbus = retrofit.create(Getbus.class);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {

            String store = editText.getText().toString(); //////store=17
            loadBus(store); 



          }
        });
      }

      private void loadBus(String bus_line){

    Call<Bus> call = getbus.select(api, appId, bus_line);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Bus>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<Bus> call, Response<Bus> response) {
       // displayBus(response.body());
        if (response.isSuccessful()){
          Log.d("Result", response.body().getBusLine());
        }else
        {
          Log.d("Resultttt",response.message());
        }

      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<Bus> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Errorr: " + t.getMessage());
      }
    });
  }

  private void displayBus(Bus showBus){
    if(showBus != null){
      String data = showBus.getBusLine();
      textView.setText(data);
    }else {
      textView.setText("No Busline");
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get text from edittext and replace to `{bus_line}` for show data

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The error message told you exactly what you're doing wrong.  Your interface should be more like this:

```
public interface Getbus {
  @GET("apis/apitraffy.php")
  Call<Bus> select(@Query("api") String api, @Query("appid") String appId, @Query("bus_line") String bus_line);
}
```

If you don't want to pass in the api and app id every time, check out request interceptors.

For logging, add this to build.gradle dependencies: `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'`

and where you build retrofit:

```
final OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

            HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            clientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);

final OkHttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();
Retrofit retrofit = retrofitBuilder
                .baseUrl(params.url)
                .client(client)
                .build();
```

Comment: Thanks ,If I change this but i have no idea to get data from edittext and replace @Query("bus_line"), How to change? ,sorry I'm newbie about android

Comment: Are you asking how to get the value of an `EditText`?  If so, I'm sure a search will lead you to the answer in minutes.  It is also possible you're not clear on how Retrofit works.  You call `getBus` and pass in the appropriate arguments.

Comment: I edited a post and I get new error ,please check for me. Thanks

Comment: I guess the URL is wrong, sounds like a 404.  I will edit the answer to show how to get full logging with retrofit.